# flash as3 Error #1009 after animation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class ro extends MovieClip {


    public function ro() {
        one.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,bu3);
        two.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,bu4);
        function bu3 (event:MouseEvent){
            trace("1");
        }
        function bu4 (event:MouseEvent){
            trace("2");
    }
    }
}
```

}

I have made an animation in the 10 first frames and in frame 11 I made two buttons to the first I gave the instance name "one" and the second button I gave the name "two" and then I started the program and I got this:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at ro()[C:\Users\cnndani\Desktop\New folder (2)\ro.as:10]
at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
at runtime::AppRunner/run()
at ADLAppEntry/run()
at global/runtime::ADLEntry()
```

what is the problem? and what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

`ro` is your document class?
When you start your program, the flash runtime examines the first frame of your animation. Because in this first frame there is no instance of anything called 'one' or 'two' (which it expects from your code as you tell it: initialize my program and assign listeners right away to 'one' and 'two') it throws an error: *`Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference`* - means: "I cannot call something on an null object" (call: addEventListener method; on: instance of one/two that are null in that frame)

You will need to wait for frame 11. In that case drop those lines from the constructor and assign an event listener there:

```
addEventListener(Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED, onFrameConstructed);

....

function onFrameConstructed(e:Event):void {
   if(this.currentFrame == 11) {
       removeEventListener(Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED, onFrameConstructed);
       one.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,bu3);
       two.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,bu4);
   }
}
```

Of course there is countless ways to do this, this was just an example.